# ¿Cómo deshabilitar la barra de texto parpadeante que aparece en las páginas web?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor

Hace poco Firefox habilitó un 'nuevo estilo por defecto' en su navegador, que es el "cursor parpadeante". Por ejemplo cuando dejas de escribir cualquier texto, hay una barra delgada al final del mismo, que aparece y desaparece; a ésta me refiero... El problema es que Firefox ahora hace que esa barra aparezca en las paginas web, cosa que antes no pasaba; y personalmente me parece desagradable. Pregunto, si alguien sabe cómo podría deshabilitarla.

Comment: Bienvenido, considera por favor añadir un ejemplo del efecto que dices que ocurre para saber a mas detalle de lo que hablas, checa de paso [ask]

Comment: ¿No es esto algo que se activa si presionas `F7`? por defecto no está activado. No sé si te refieres a lo mismo que me estoy refiriendo, de lo contrario sería bueno una captura de pantalla o un pequeño `gif`.

Answer (score -1):

Eso lo puedes lograr colocando en tu input la propiedad de estilo transparent, puedes hacerlo mediante css o aplicandolo directamente al HTML

```html
<input type="text" style="color: transparent;text-shadow: 0 0 0 red;"/>
```

Comment: Funciona! Pero el problema es que Firefox te pone este estilo a todo texto de la pagina web. Si quieres puedes comprobarlo abriendo tu navegador. O sea  no hay un input especifico. Y entonces no se a que exactamente ponerle "color : transparent".. si le pongo a todos los elementos (*), me va a poner letra transparente a mis divs, articulos, etc

Comment: Si lo haces en css utiliza el selector `input[type="text"]`

Comment: La regla quedaria 

input[type="text"] {
 color: transparent;
}